# solvability of quintic equation over local fields

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

It is known that we cannot generally solve the polynomial equation by radicals (Abel-Ruffini theorem). Also, we know that the zeros of $f(x)\in K[x]$ can be expressed by radicals of $K$ if and only if the Galois group is solvable.

However, in case of local fields, field extensions are solvable in general, so there might be a radical formula for the polynomial equation even for degree $\geq 5$. Is this true? I'm slightly confusing now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here -> http://www.emba.uvm.edu/~ddummit/quintics/solvable.pdf for a paper by Dummit giving a formula for the roots of a solvable quintic.

Comment: You should first make sure you understand the answer to your question in the case when $K = \mathbf{R}$ (or even $\mathbf{C}$).

Comment: If there were a formula involving only the coefficients of $f$ — I think that that’s the understanding of what it means for there to *be* a formula — then that formula would have to work over any field of the same characteristic as $K$. And we know that there is no such formula.

Comment: @sharding4 Thanks, that looks interesting.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you. Now I think I know how stupid my question is. Solvability by radicals does not give any information about general formula.

Comment: @Lubin Thank you for the same reasons as Gordon. (It seems that we cannot tag more than one people at the same time)

Comment: @Lubin I know it's a very old question, but why such a formula would have to work over any field of the same characteristic? Why a formula over $\mathbb{C}$ should work over $\mathbb{Q}$? I really don't understand that.

Comment: What is  “formula”, @Mark? What could make a $\Bbb C$-valid formula suddenly invalid when the coefficients were rational numbers? Don’t forget: no using sines and cosines, logs and exponentials.

Comment: @Lubin Sure. But when the formula is over $\mathbb{C}$ we are allowed to use any complex numbers in it, right? Yes, such a formula would work for polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as well. But is it true there is no formula over $\mathbb{Q}$ where we can use any complex numbers? What I know is that there is no formula over $\mathbb{Q}$ where we only use rational numbers and the coefficients. (because for example $x^5-6x+3$ is not solvable by radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$. Over $\mathbb{C}$ this polynomial is solvable though)

Comment: Where’s your complex formula for $x^5-6x+3$? If it doesn’t work for $x^5-9x+3$, it’s not a formula.

Comment: @Lubin Oh, I get it. Thanks.